# Why do I get a constant 0 fps in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-clock, pygame-tick

I am not getting any frames even though I have set my clock tick to 60 and it is in the right space. I also know its not my computer because I have run larger games with better frames. Also it cant be the indentation because I have it intended correctly.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

gameclock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = str(int(gameclock.get_fps()))

playerX = 250
playerY = 250
playerSpeed = 3

playerFrontImg = pygame.image.load("Images/PlayerImages/playerFront.png")
playerRightImg = pygame.image.load("Images/PlayerImages/playerRight.png")
playerBackImg = pygame.image.load("Images/PlayerImages/playerBack.png")
playerLeftImg = pygame.transform.flip(playerRightImg, True, False)


playercurrentImg = playerFrontImg


running = True
while running:
    gameclock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY -= playerSpeed
                playercurrentImg = playerBackImg

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += playerSpeed
                playercurrentImg = playerFrontImg

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += playerSpeed
                playercurrentImg = playerRightImg

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= playerSpeed
                playercurrentImg = playerLeftImg

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                playerY += 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                playerY += 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX += 0

    playerRect = playercurrentImg.get_rect(topleft = (playerX, playerY))
    screen.fill((255, 255, 100))
    print(fps)
    screen.blit(playercurrentImg, (playerX, playerY))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been struggling with this issue for awhile now.
Is there any other tips on how I should organize my code.

Comment: You should recalculate `fps` each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke [`get_fps()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.get_fps) in the application loop:

> Compute your game's framerate (in frames per second). It is computed by averaging the last ten calls to `Clock.tick()`.

```py
gameclock = pygame.time.Clock()

# [...]

running = True
while running:
    gameclock.tick(60)
    fps = str(int(gameclock.get_fps()))
    
    # [...]
```

---

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement:

```py
running = True
while running:
    gameclock.tick(60)
    fps = str(int(gameclock.get_fps()))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        playerY -= playerSpeed
        playercurrentImg = playerBackImg

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        playerY += playerSpeed
        playercurrentImg = playerFrontImg

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        playerX += playerSpeed
        playercurrentImg = playerRightImg

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        playerX -= playerSpeed
        playercurrentImg = playerLeftImg

    # [...]
```

Comment: If I have the constant fps why does my character not move smoothly

Comment: @Elfed I've extended the answer.

Comment: I used your code but I still need to press the keys each time to move

Comment: @Elfed Did you respect the indentation? The code is in the application loop not in the event loop.

Comment: Now I did and it works, thank you so much.